# Find distance between each Location points in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In PostGres Database having a Column "location" with geography datatype and another column "time".The time and location points are stored in lot of rows.I want to find the distance between the each locations.For that how to query in PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what relevance the time column has (oh - you're probably better off not using that as a column-name since it's already a type name). There are different ways to calculate distance and if you've not found it yet, I highly recommend the PostGIS documentation:

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/